# Two tables One class

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, mapping, relational-database

Problem: Two tables One class
can anyone help me map declaratively Order with hibernate in order.hbm.xml ??

I have One pojo Order with following properties
userId comes from object User
and Map includes Item name and quantity of Item in basket

Order

```
private int userId
private int orderId
private Map<Item, Integer> basket
```

Item

```
private int itemId
private String name
private double price
```

User

```
private int userId
private String userName
private String password
private String firstName
private String lastName
```

my tables summary is below
Order ID is primary key in UserOrder and foreign key in Orders
in orders Order ID and and Item ID are composite Primary key

Tables

```
UserOrder
---------
USERID NUMBER
ORDERID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY

ORDERS
-------
ORDERID NUMBER
ITEMID NUMBER
QUANTITY NUMBER
```

Answer (score 0):

A User can place many Orders; an Order can contain one or more Items.  So it's standard one-to-many relationships in Hibernate.

I wouldn't recommend using a Map to hold Item; use a List or Set.  You already have quantity as an attribute on Item.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I had a typo it was price rather quantity in Item
Item is key and quantity is stored as value against each key making it a basket(map).
I am very new and I need some examples regarding how to map it.
I will be grateful if you could help.

Comment: No, you'll have an Item class with a quantity attribute.  No need for a Map.  I'm not providing examples.  Look at the Hibernate docs at one-to-many and how to do it.

Comment: @Aahil: Same as duffy said: don't use a Map. Make your model more object-oriented. Try your hand at mapping it and come back with specific problems.